# setHours and setMinutes function not working right JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some dates. What is doing here is to set hours and minutes to new values but It was working right while I was in Windows but now In ubuntu, it's not working right?

```
starting_recording_date = new Date(date)
starting_recording_date.setHours(starting_hour);
starting_recording_date.setMinutes(starting_minutes);
starting_recording_date.setSeconds(0);
```

Am using the above code and my data looks like

```
[ 2016-10-12T00:00:00.000Z]
```

I wanted to set hours and minutes to `3Hour 0Minutes`,

But the resulting values are `2016-10-11T22:00:00.000Z`

I don't know why but its taking 3 as 22.

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

UPDATE:
Its working good in my console of browser But still not good in terminal.

[image]

Comment: Whats the system clock set to?

Comment: My clock is only to PKT time which is Karachi.

Comment: You're working in `+0500` timezone, but dump result in `UTC` timezone.